# Submitting a form using an anchor

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop creating a number of `<form>` elements.
Each `<form>` contains a unique hidden `URL` parameter.

Is there a way to link each `<form>` with corresponding `<anchor>`, so that when the link is clicked the corresponding form is submitted?

```
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method','GET');
f.setAttribute('action','example.com');

var api = '&param=1';

var filters = document.createElement('input');
filters.setAttribute('type','hidden');
filters.setAttribute('name','filters');
filters.value = api;

f.appendChild(filters);
document.getElementById('body').appendChild(f);

document.getElementById('formAnchors').innerHTML += '<li class=""><a href="#" role="button">ClickMe</a></li>';
```

Comment: `f.submit()` would submit the form, doing `myAnchor.addEventListener("click", function(){ f.submit(); })` would submit it when the anchor is clicked. This is overkill for `GET` anyway since you can usually just go to the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('href', '#');
anchor.setAttribute('role', 'button');
anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    f.submit();
});

var li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(anchor);
document.getElementById('formAnchors').appendChild(li);
```

If you'll have multiple anchors and forms, I suggest you give the forms IDs, and put the ID in a `data-form` attribute in the corresponding anchor. Then you can use the same event listener function for all the anchors:

```
function anchor_submit(e) {
    var form = e.target.getAttribute('data-form');
    e.preventDefault();
    form.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it. I didn't check it for errors but if you're creating the forms in a loop you'll need to call a function like this one so that you don't run into variable scope issues with your events. [IDs and other identifying attributes are unnecessary]

```
function addForm(url, api, getpost) {
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method',getpost?getpost:'GET');
f.setAttribute('action',url);

var filters = document.createElement('input');
filters.setAttribute('type','hidden');
filters.setAttribute('name','filters');
filters.value = api?api:'&param=1';

var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('href', '#');
anchor.setAttribute('role', 'button');
anchor.innerHTML='Click Me';
anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    f.submit();
});

f.appendChild(filters);
document.getElementById('body').appendChild(f);
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(anchor);
document.getElementById('formAnchors').appendChild(li);

return f;
}
```